# Rewriting basic functions in polar form

Tags: polar-coordinates

I've been exploring how to rewrite common parent functions ($x^2, \sqrt x$,...) in polar form.

Is it possible to rewrite natural log or trig functions in polar form as a function of $\theta$?

For example, I tried to rewrite $ln(x)$ using simple substitution:

$y=ln(x)$

$r\cdot sin(\theta)=ln(r\cdot cos(\theta))$

And I assume after this I am unable to separate the r's.  I find the same issue with sin, cosine, exponential...

Also, if it is impossible, is there an explanation why aside from the fact that the variables can't separate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the problems comes from the fact that for common functions such a dependence $r=r(\theta)$ will be multivalued (logarithm is concave, so you are lucky, at most two values for a given $\theta\in(-\pi/2,\pi/2)$; trigonometric functions - not even close, the numer of values taken by $r(\theta)$ depends heavily on $\theta$).

Another problem is that such dependence will almost never be expressed in terms of common functions.

Comment: I understand the mult-value issue.  I wonder if we could make a piecewise function to the same effect?  Or define a domain so that it is a function?

We could choose to use the closest r from the origin to $(x,ln(x))$, and not go past the angle which I understand the cartesian point would be $(e,1)$.  The domain we would look for is on $(-\pi/2,tan^-1(1/e))$  It reminds me very much of the definition of inverse trig functions.

Comment: Of course, we can consider $\theta \in(-\pi/2,0]$, then on this interval the relation $r\sin\theta=\ln(r\cos \theta)$ can be inversed and we obtain a well-defined function $r=r(\theta)$ by an implicit function theorem. However, we can not find an explicit form of this function without Lambert's W-function. The existence of inverse trigonometric functions can be seen as a particular case of an implicit function theorem.

Comment: That makes sense.  I'll need to investigate the implicit function theorem. Thank you!